App input keeps getting reset to the initial value
I have the following shiny app. When I select a metric in the ui, it switches for a second and then resets.
The comments show some of the things I tried.
#===============================================================================

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  MyDT1 <-
    structure(list(MinuteOfDay = structure(c(1716379200, 1716379500,
                                             1716379800, 1716380100, 1716380400, 1716380700, 1716381000, 1716381300,
                                             1716381600, 1716381900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
                   AgentCategory = c("Core", "Core", "Core", "Core", "Core",
                                     "Core", "Core", "Core", "Core", "Core"), variable = structure(c(1L,
                                                                                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Queue",
                                                                                                                                                     "Login", "Tier", "Abr_Actuals", "Abr_Preds", "Abr_Diff"), class = "factor"),
                   value = c(2, 0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 0, 4), AsOfDate = structure(c(19865,
                                                                                   19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865
                   ), class = "Date"), MinuteOfDay_TIME = structure(c(25200,
                                                                      25500, 25800, 26100, 26400, 26700, 27000, 27300, 27600, 27900
                   ), units = "secs", class = c("hms", "difftime"))), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                    -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
  MyDT2 <-
    structure(list(MinuteOfDay = structure(c(1716379200, 1716379500,
                                             1716379800, 1716380100, 1716380400, 1716380700, 1716381000, 1716381300,
                                             1716381600, 1716381900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
                   AgentCategory = c("Core", "Core", "Core", "Core", "Core",
                                     "Core", "Core", "Core", "Core", "Core"), variable = structure(c(2L,
                                                                                                     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Queue",
                                                                                                                                                     "Login", "Tier", "Abr_Actuals", "Abr_Preds", "Abr_Diff"), class = "factor"),
                   value = c(20, 30, 10, 24, 24, 24, 20, 10, 50, 40), AsOfDate = structure(c(19865,
                                                                                   19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865
                   ), class = "Date"), MinuteOfDay_TIME = structure(c(25200,
                                                                      25500, 25800, 26100, 26400, 26700, 27000, 27300, 27600, 27900
                   ), units = "secs", class = c("hms", "difftime"))), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                    -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
  
  MyDT <- rbind(MyDT1, MyDT2)
  
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    filtered_data_1 <- reactive({
      subset(MyDT, 
             as.character(MyDT$variable) %in% as.character(input$Metric1) & 
               as.Date(MyDT$AsOfDate) %in% as.Date(input$Date1))
    })
    

    
    # observeEvent(filtered_data_1(), {
    #   updateSelectInput(session, 
    #                     "Metric1",
    #                     label = "Metric1",
    #                     choices = filtered_data_1()$variable,
    #                     selected = NULL 
    #   )
    # })
    # 
    
    
    
    
    # current_Metric1 <- reactiveVal()
    # 
    # observe({
    #   current_Metric1(input$Metric1)  
    # })
    # 
    # # as normal except notice that
    # # `current_in2()` sets the pre-selected choices 
    # observeEvent(eventExpr = input$current_Metric1,
    #              handlerExpr = {
    #                updateSelectInput(
    #                  session = session,
    #                  inputId = "current_Metric1",
    #                  label = "current_Metric1",
    #                  # keep what we had before
    #                  selected = current_Metric1(),
    #                  choices = MyDT[MyDT$Metric1 %in% input$Metric1, "variable"]
    #                )
    #              })
    # 
    
    

    # observe({
    #   updateSelectInput(session, 
    #                     "Metric1", 
    #                     choices = filtered_data_1()$variable,
    #                     selected = isolate(input$Metric1)
    #                     )
    # })
    # 
    # observe({
    #   updateSelectInput(session, 
    #                     "Date1", 
    #                     choices = filtered_data_1()$AsOfDate,
    #                     selected = isolate(input$Date1)
    #                     )
    # })
    
    # observeEvent(filtered_data_1(), {
    #   updateSelectInput(session, 
    #                     "Metric1",
    #                      choices = unique(filtered_data_1()$variable),
    #                      selected = NULL 
    #   )
    # })
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "Date1", choices = MyDT$AsOfDate)
    updateSelectInput(session, "Metric1", choices = MyDT$variable)

    ggplot(data = filtered_data_1(),
           aes(x = MinuteOfDay,
               y = value)) +
      geom_point(stat = "identity", col = "black") +
      geom_line(stat = "identity", linewidth = 1.6, col = "red") + 
      labs(x = "MinuteOfDay", y = input$Metric1) +
      ggtitle(paste0("Time Series: ", input$Metric1, sep = "")) +
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(size=16, face= "bold", colour= "black", hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t=10,b=-20)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=16, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"), # bold
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black" ),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA)
      )  +
      theme_classic()  
    
  })

  

}


#===============================================================================

message("app: Create UI  \n")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("ABR Dashboard"),
  
  tabsetPanel(      
    
    tabPanel("Time Series",
             sidebarLayout(
               selectInput(inputId = "Date1", 
                           label = "Select Date", 
                           choices = c("")
               ),
               selectInput(inputId = "Metric1",
                           label = "Which Metric",
                           choices = c("")
               )
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("distPlot1")
             )
    )
  )
)

#===============================================================================

message("app: Import Packages \n")

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

#===============================================================================


The resason your app resets is that you update your selectInputs every time you draw the plot.  Which happens every time you change one of the selectInputs.  It's a vicious circle.  Since you don't specify a value in your updateSelectInputs, the first element of choices is selected.  Hence the reset.
It's also a very bad idea to nest reactives.
So, replace your existing renderPlot call with
  filtered_data_1 <- reactive({
    subset(MyDT, 
           as.character(MyDT$variable) %in% as.character(input$Metric1) & 
             as.Date(MyDT$AsOfDate) %in% as.Date(input$Date1))
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "Date1", choices = MyDT$AsOfDate)
    updateSelectInput(session, "Metric1", choices = MyDT$variable)
  })
  
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = filtered_data_1(),
           aes(x = MinuteOfDay,
               y = value)) +
      geom_point(stat = "identity", col = "black") +
      geom_line(stat = "identity", linewidth = 1.6, col = "red") + 
      labs(x = "MinuteOfDay", y = input$Metric1) +
      ggtitle(paste0("Time Series: ", input$Metric1, sep = "")) +
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(size=16, face= "bold", colour= "black", hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t=10,b=-20)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=16, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"), # bold
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black" ),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA)
      )  +
      theme_classic()  
  })

and include library(ggplot2) (or library(tidyverse)) somewhere in your code and you should be good to go.

PS: We didn't really need about fifty lines of commented code and another ten of theme modifications (at least some of which, by the way, are overridden by your final call to theme_classic()) to illustrate your problem.  Both "minimal" and "reproducible" are important features of a question that is easy to answer.
